# Как сохранить результат выполнения скрипта в таблицу?

Tags: php, таблицы

После каждого выполнения скрипта на php получаю определенное число.
Как сохранить результат выполнения скрипта в таблицу?
Что бы каждый последующий результат записывался в новую ячейку...

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "таблицей" ? Это таблица в html на экране или может в БД. Или еще где нибудь

Comment: таблица в html на экране.

Comment: А как происходит обращение к php скрипту ? Если страница перегружается полностью, то значит php должен накапливать результаты на своей стороне, на сервере и отдавать полностью много чисел. А если вы воспользуетесь ajax, то на javascript на странице пишите скрипт который получает очередное число вызвав php и самостоятельно добавляет его в таблицу, создав новый элемент <td>

Comment: Сейчас работает после перезагрузки страницы. Но в дальнейшем он должен будет выполняться  каждый час. В JS легче, там setTimeout (). В PHP только пытаюсь вникнуть... Удобнее всего думаю через CRON но не понимаю как реализовать, что бы каждый час после выполнения скрипта предыдущая цифра не терялась, а записывалась а идеале в таблицу html...

Comment: setTimeout на час не надежен. Вкладку браузера могут закрыть. И даже если ее не закроют а с нее переключатся то время выполнения может сдвигаться как угодно. Или могут раз в минуту нажимать обновить и ваш php скрипт будет запускаться заново. И что надо делать если к вам пришли 2 клиента, у них разные числа или одни и те же ? В общем думаю в вашем случае надо создавать все по расписанию и сохранять в какой нибудь БД. А при обращении клиента отдавать все что есть в этой БД (ну или не все, а как удобно)

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте через CRON.
Создайте скрипт php, который будет возвращать число, и этот файл (с функцией или как Вам будет удобно) поместите в задачи CRON.